# How do I add new elements in a list from another list?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

I have a project that goes like this:

Variables:

```
j_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
finish_act = [1, 3]
on_going = [5, 6, 7]
q_active = [2]
completion_time = [0, 0, 5, 0, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Code:

```
t = 12
for sec in on_going:
    indx = j_set.index(sec)
    if completion_time[indx] == t:
        finish_act.append(j_set[indx])
        on_going.remove(j_set[indx])

print(finish_act)
print(on_going)
```

The objective is at a certain time period, if an activity finishes at time `t` then it should be added to `finish_act`.

If more than one activity is finished, then these activities should be added to `finish_act`.

In the code that I have so far, both `5 and 6` in `on_going` are finished at time, `t = 12` based on the `completion_time`. But with this code, only one of them is selected and added in `finish_act`.

Is there a way to upgrade the code I have so far so that it will take such cases into consideration?

Any help/suggestion/materials to read on will be appreciated! Thank you!

Expected output:

```
finish_act = [1, 3, 5, 6]
on_going = [7]
```

Comment: `finish_act.extend(on_going); on_going = []`

Comment: @slackmart edited my post to account for cases such that there is another number in on_going that is not finish at time t = 12, so it will have to remain in on_going.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a filter with a lambda for selecting the values we want to append to the `finish_act` list. Then you can iterate over the same list and remove the items from `on_going`.

```
>>> on_time = list(
...     filter(lambda x: completion_time[j_set.index(x)] == t, on_going)
... )
>>> finish_act.extend(on_time)
>>> [on_going.remove(x) for x in on_time]
[None, None]
```

Be aware, you need to catch the ValueError and IndexError exceptions in order to follow best practices.

Comment: what is the name valid?

Comment: I think it supposed to be for on_time. Am I right? Thanks for this, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the two list to make one:

```
list_final = list1 + list2
```

Then you could shuffle this if you wanted:

```
import random
random.shuffle(list_final)
```

I am sorry if this did not help you but hopefully it did.